# What is the equivalent of the mysql_insert_id() function in sqlserver?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What is the equivalent of the mysql_insert_id() MySQL function in sqlserver ?

Comment: [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following

[SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

[IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)

[@@IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: If I use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)` what is the FROM clause ?

Comment: There is no from CLAUSE, this is a function, not a table/view